# How to auto resize rectangle in artist-mode while writing in it?

Tags: artist-mode

I use the `artist-mode` more than i can count, and mostly use the rectangle form, especially when writing (my own mindmap/concept map workflow that i come to like) but i always have to fix the part myself when writing inside of it.

Any ways to make the rectangle in `artist-mode` auto resize or prevent them from breaking when writing inside of it? (as if it was it's own buffer/windows, so text don't go over the limits of the rectangle, without the form breaking)

Comment: I know isn't a general solution (I barely touched `artist-mode`), but what about writing first and then warp region between point and mark in a rectangle using `C-c C-r`?

Comment: Yeah, i did try this among other trick i found, but what i want is a bit more, shall we say "seamless", mostly because i was used a lot to the workflow of vim + [this gem](https://github.com/gyim/vim-boxdraw) and couldn't find anything else beside `artist-mode`.

It basically auto resize (and prevent the form to break), and i'm sure it is possible in elisp, though i don't know myself how :) @Muihlinn

Comment: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352871/).

Comment: Yes, and while i tried what was showed on the answer on the aforementioned post, they didn't work: mainly, once you quit untabify mode, or go back to plain `artist-mode` it then break the form at some point... @awllower

So while this is a similar post, the intent is different as my question is clearly stating "auto resize" but the other post, while it does show similarities, the question isn't as explicit.